# Format of unnumbered chapter in TOC to be equal to the format of numbered chapter

Tags: table-of-contents, classicthesis

I am using `classicthesis` and `arsclassica` to write my thesis.

I have used `\addchap` to add a unnumbered chapter, that is automatically added to the TOC. However, the graphic format/font of those unnumbered chapters is different, and I would like to make it equal to the format of the numbered chapters?

[image: Imgur]

In the image, I would like to change "Sommario,Abstract,Introduzione" to be equale to LOREM (and also, if possible, to align them to the L)

```
\documentclass[10pt,%                    
               a4paper,%                  
               twoside,openright,%        
%              oneside,openany,%         
               titlepage,%               
               headinclude,,footinclude,%  
               BCOR5mm,%                  
               cleardoublepage=empty,%    
               captions=tableheading,%       
               ]{scrreprt}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}       

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,%        
            beramono,%                   
            eulermath,%                    
            pdfspacing,%                 
            listings,%                  
%           parts,%                       
            ]{classicthesis}   
\usepackage{arsclassica}    
\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\pagenumbering{gobble}


\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}} 
\cleardoublepage

\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\deftripstyle{pgnumtopouter}{}{}{\pagemark}{}{}{}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pgnumtopouter}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark{Sommario}{Sommario}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax

\addchap{Sommario}

Qui Abstract in italiano

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\vfill

\selectlanguage{english}
\pdfbookmark{Abstract}{Abstract}

\addchap{Abstract}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
Qui abstract in inglese

\selectlanguage{italian}

\endgroup           

\vfill

\chapter{Lorem}
\label{cap:lorem}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer MWE added.

Comment: I have added a possible solution, the additional `\pdfbookmarks` are not necessary, this is done by `\addchap` already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get the alignment as well as the correct font, one way is to write nothing to the toc and use `\addcontentsline` with an empty chapter number as first argument of `\numberline{}{...}` 
The command `\spacedlowsmallcaps` from the `arsclassica` package is used to write the 'chapter' title within the TOC line.

I have added a wrapper, which automatically does this for your setup, assuming, that the chapter title is also intended as entry to the toc.

Please not the difference between `\addchap` and `\addchapextended`, I just did `\addchap{Sommario}` effectively twice.

**Extended version**

```
\documentclass[10pt,%                    
               a4paper,%                  
               twoside,openright,%        
%              oneside,openany,%         
               titlepage,%               
               headinclude,,footinclude,%  
               BCOR5mm,%                  
               cleardoublepage=empty,%    
               captions=tableheading,%       
               ]{scrreprt}    
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}       

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,%        
            beramono,%                   
            eulermath,%                    
            pdfspacing,%                 
            listings,%                  
%           parts,%                       
            ]{classicthesis}   
\usepackage{arsclassica}    


%\newcommand{\addchapextended}[1]{%  Old version without alignment
%\addchap[\noexpand\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}]{#1}%
%}%




\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addchapextended}[1]{%
\phantomsection%


\makeatletter
\newcommand{\addchapextended}[1]{%
\phantomsection%
\addchap[]{#1}%  Do the unnumbered chapter head in the content section 
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}} 
\pdfbookmark[0]{#1}{\thepage::\thechapter}%
%Add a contentsline to the TOC, omit the chapter number and align correctly
\begingroup%
\renewcommand{\Hy@writebookmark}[5]{}{}{}{}{}%   Drop the automatic writing of bookmarks by addcontentsline%
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{%
\numberline{}{\noexpand\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}%
\endgroup%
}%
\makeatother%



\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 
\pagenumbering{gobble}


\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}} 
\cleardoublepage

\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\deftripstyle{pgnumtopouter}{}{}{\pagemark}{}{}{}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pgnumtopouter}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
%\pdfbookmark{Sommario}{Sommario}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax

%\phantomsection
%\chapter*{Sommario}%
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect{\scshape Sommario}}

\addchapextended{Sommario}%
\addchap{Sommario}


%\addchap[\noexpand\MakeTextLowercase{\sffamily\textsc{Sommario}}]{Sommario}%

%\addchap[\sffamily\textsc{Lorem}]{Sommario}%

Qui Abstract in italiano

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\vfill

\selectlanguage{english}
\pdfbookmark{Abstract}{Abstract}

\addchapextended{Abstract}
\addchapextended{Lorem}

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
Qui abstract in inglese

\selectlanguage{italian}

\endgroup           

\vfill

\chapter{Lorem}
\label{cap:lorem}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum

\chapter{Lorem Nr. 2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Just a detail: is there a way to align, for example, SOMMARIO to the L of the chapter "1  LOREM"?

Comment: @thunder1123: I think about it. At first glance, it is not that easy ;-)

Comment: @thunder1123: Updated `;-)`

Comment: @thunder1123: There is a little problem with the bookmark, of "Sommario" and other ones -- they are not aligned with the rest, I do not know why, but there is a remedy ;-)

Comment: Ah! That's true! What is the remedy?

Comment: @thunder1123: I added the `remedy` ;-) `\addcontentsline` is the cause, it must be prevented, that it will use the hyperref bookmarking command directly. So I redefine `\Hy@writebookmark` command to do nothing and then add `\pdfbookmark` by hand. Since it is inside a group, the redefinition does no no harm outside.

Comment: It works, but I spotted another problem, with your redefinition of the \addchap: for the second,third page, the page number should appear along with the chapter name (see for example page 14 of your mwe for the correct behaviour). Ah, this thing is coming much harder than I thought

Comment: @thunder1123: Do you mean the page number in the toc?

Comment: no, the page number in the heading of each page

Comment: @thunder1123: I think, I know what you mean: the living `column title`, something like `1 | Sommario`, which is not present at the moment!

Comment: Yes,that's it! Actually, to be coherent with the rest of the pages, on the first page of each chapter, there should be only the number, but from the second page onwards, there should be 2| SOMMARIO, 3| SOMMARIO,ecc ....

Comment: @thunder1123: Well, that was rather easy: Adding `\markboth{...}` etc to the `\addchapextended{} command.

Comment: @thunder1123: You are right, I meant of course `3 | Sommario`, the 1st page should not have that format at all.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses the `titletoc` package:

```
\documentclass[10pt,%
               a4paper,%
               twoside,openright,%
% oneside,openany,%
               titlepage,%
               headinclude,,footinclude,%
               BCOR5mm,%
               cleardoublepage=empty,%
               captions=tableheading,%
               ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,%
 beramono,%
 eulermath,%
 pdfspacing,%
 %listings,%
% parts,%
 ]{classicthesis}
\usepackage{arsclassica}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{titletoc}
 \titlecontents{chapter}[1.44em]{\smallskip}%\vspace{1cm}
 {{\contentslabel[\thecontentslabel.]{1.25em}}}%numbered
 {\spacedlowsmallcaps}%numberless
 {\quad\contentspage}[\medskip]%


\begin{document}
\hypersetup{pageanchor=false}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\pagenumbering{gobble}


\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{tableofcontents}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\tableofcontents
\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}
\cleardoublepage

\hypersetup{pageanchor=true}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\deftripstyle{pgnumtopouter}{}{}{\pagemark}{}{}{}
\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{pgnumtopouter}

\cleardoublepage
\phantomsection
\pdfbookmark{Sommario}{Sommario}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\let\cleardoublepage\relax

\addchap{Sommario}

Qui Abstract in italiano

\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\vfill

\selectlanguage{english}
\pdfbookmark{Abstract}{Abstract}

\addchap{Abstract}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
Qui abstract in inglese

\selectlanguage{italian}

\endgroup

\vfill

\chapter{Lorem}
\label{cap:lorem}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been using `classicthesis` and had the same problem. The answers here wouldn't help me, but guided me to a solution.

For new chapters, I am now using `\addchap{\tocEntry{>CHAPTERNAME<}}`, which appears both in the pdf as well as in small caps in the LoC.

For the contents, where you would receive a toc-entry automatically but not in the `classicthesis` style, I used this (here for the LoC):

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{{\tocEntry{\contentsname}}}%
\tableofcontents
```

For `glossaries`, I needed another workaround, which is:

```
\renewcommand{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\addchap{\tocEntry{Symbols}}
\printglossary[type=symbols]

\newpage

\addchap{\tocEntry{Acronyms}}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
```

I hope this helps tackling the next readers issues as well.
Cheers!